# Change 'Events In' Title in Events Calendar Plugin by Modern Tribe

Tags: wordpress, events, plugins

I am using the plugin The Events Calendar by Modern Tribe and I need to change the test in the date box that says 'Events In' to 'Search Events'.  I tried looking through the files for it to find it but have had no luck in finding that section.

[image: This is the what I need to change]

You can also see it via the test version on my website http://www.richardclifford.net/events/

Can anyone tell me how to change this and/or what function I need to add in order to change it?